# How do I get final value of += operator in php?

Tags: php

I want to get final value of $score in the code below

```
    foreach($request->jawaban as $key => $value){
        $soal = Soal::find($key);
        $kunci = $soal->kunci;    
        $score = 0;
        if($value === $kunci){
           $score+=1;

           echo $score;
        }
    }
```

but its produce value

```
123456789101112131415161718192021
```

how do I get 21 value only?

Comment: Not sure if you forgot to add a loop? Please add `if` statement in a loop and `echo` outside the loop.

Comment: So my original comment stands. You need to move the `echo $score;` after the `foreach` loop.

Comment: You also needs to move `$score = 0;` before  you start the foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to echo after loop. As below:

```
    $score = 0; //define this variable before loop
    foreach($request->jawaban as $key => $value){
        $soal = Soal::find($key);
        $kunci = $soal->kunci;    
        if($value === $kunci){
           $score+=1;
        }
    }
    echo $score; // echo after loop end
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: That if isn’t a loop.

Comment: Oh yes, it is if not any loop.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what others have said:  But just to show you the full code

```
$score = 0; //define this before the loop

foreach($request->jawaban as $key => $value){
    $soal = Soal::find($key);
    $kunci = $soal->kunci;    

    if($value === $kunci) $score+=1; //simplify this, as I am lazy coder.
}

echo $score; //echo the final value, after the loop finishes.
```

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize $score before the loop and also print the output after loop.

```
$score = 0; 
foreach($request->jawaban as $key => $value){
    $soal = Soal::find($key);
    $kunci = $soal->kunci;    
    if($value === $kunci){
       $score+=1;
    }
}
echo $score;
```